# aiohttp_utils: gunicorn doesn't fully reload and doesn't rebuild pyc files

Tags: macos, gunicorn, python-3.6, aiohttp

The [aiohttp_utils gunicorn server](https://aiohttp-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/runner.html), with `reload` option activated, does not fully restart the development server when a .py is updated.

For the test, I added a `print ("STARTING...")` at the beginning of my `myapp.py` file.

```
STARTING...
[2017-03-06 17:17:01 +0100] [5299] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.0
[2017-03-06 17:17:01 +0100] [5299] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:5002 (5299)
[2017-03-06 17:17:01 +0100] [5299] [INFO] Using worker: aiohttp_utils.runner.GunicornWorker
[2017-03-06 17:17:01 +0100] [5308] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 5308
```

I update and save file myapp.py, I then can read:

```
[2017-03-06 17:17:47 +0100] [5308] [INFO] Worker reloading: /.../myapp.py modified
[2017-03-06 17:17:48 +0100] [5308] [INFO] Stopping server: 5308, connections: 0
[2017-03-06 17:17:48 +0100] [5308] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 5308)
[2017-03-06 17:17:48 +0100] [5339] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 5339
```

The app was not reloaded on the browser.
File `myapp.cpython-36.pyc` was not updated in `__pycache__`, and the module was not rerun, (no "STARTING...")

NB: The `__pycache__` directory has correct user rights.

I run myapp like this:

```
from aiohttp_utils import run
import myapp
run(app=myapp.app, app_uri='myapp:app', host='127.0.0.1', reload=True, port=5002)
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `aiohttp_utils`, try using the more updated [aiohttp-devtools](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/aiohttp-devtools) package for autoreloading.